# Changing UI before callback runs in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a `Angular.js` App, I have this function. I want when this called, a loading DIV appears and then `callback()` runs:

```
$scope.startLoading = function (callback) {
    $scope.animation =true; //binded to UI and setting this changes UI
    $scope.errors = false; //binded to UI and setting this changes UI

    callback(); //callback function runs(uploading file) and after that, UI changes!
};
```

But problem is that it seems in `Angular`, any changes in UI, affected after finishing that function.

Right now, my first two variable sets and then `callback()` runs and this does a heavy task and after that heavy task UI updates! But this is what I want: when this function called, first that variables changes and because of them UI changes and a loading DIV appears, and after that, callback runs and that heavy task starts... How I can achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on your question a bit.  Are you saying you want the two variables to be set, then the callback runs and when that finishes, the two variables get set back to an original value?

Answer (score 0):

The changes to the UI aren't being processed because a `$digest` cycle hasn't occurred: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest

You can use a $timeout to evaluate the callback after the next digest cycle, eg:

```
$scope.startLoading = function (callback) {
    $scope.animation =true; //binded to UI and setting this changes UI
    $scope.errors = false; //binded to UI and setting this changes UI

    // Delay the callback by 10ms
    $timeout(callback, 10); //callback function runs(uploading file) and after that, UI changes!
};
```

Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jw2hIAzYRTHCHwaVVAJg?p=preview

Comment: then is this a proper way? if first two lines before timeout takes more than 500 what happens? i will have the same strange behavior again?

Comment: The timeout is so that the browser has time to render the updated ng-show. You can use a shorter timeout, 10ms is likely enough. You can try $timeout(callback, 0) but on some browsers the 0 timeout doesn't let the browser update in time.

If you want your long running task to truly be asynchronous, then take a look at Web Workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers